# Animation File Input Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, animation

I am trying to create an animation when the user chooses a File in the InputFile. But it only runs when I reload the page. So I don't see how I can fix this problem.
Here is my code.

Html Erb (Rails) :

```
 <div class="box" id="Box">
     <%= f.label 'Upload Your Song !', class:'label1', for:'fileUpload' %>
     <%= f.label 'Size: 15mb max', class:'label2', for:'fileUpload' %>
     <%= f.file_field :video, id:'fileUpload', style:'opacity:0;position:absolute;' %>
     <%= f.label 'Choose your file', for:'fileUpload', class:'btn-hover color-1 flex' %>
 </div>
```

Script Javascript :

```
<script>
    var Browse = document.getElementById("fileUpload")
    var File = document.getElementById("Box");
    var Upload = document.getElementById("Uploader");
    if( Browse.files.length != 0 ){
        File.animate([
          { transform: 'translateY(0px)' },
          { transform: 'translateY(-150px)' }
        ], {
          duration: 1000,
        });
      window.setTimeout( function() {
        File.className += ' fade-in';
      }, 50);
      window.setTimeout( function() {
        File.style.display = 'none';
      }, 1050);
    }
</script>
```

CSS :

```
.fade-in {
    opacity: 0;
    transition:             opacity 1s;
        -moz-transition:    opacity 1s;
        -ms-transition:     opacity 1s;
        -o-transition:      opacity 1s;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are going to want to have this run when that input is changed. Maybe using the `onChange` event:

```js
var browseInput = document.getElementById("fileUpload")
browseInput.onchange = function() {
  var fileBox = document.getElementById("Box");
  if( browseInput.files.length != 0 ){
      fileBox.animate([
        { transform: 'translateY(0px)' },
        { transform: 'translateY(-150px)' }
      ], {
        duration: 1000,
      });
    window.setTimeout( function() {
      fileBox.className += ' fade-in';
    }, 50);
    window.setTimeout( function() {
      fileBox.style.display = 'none';
    }, 1050);
  }
}
```